# Use dtreeviz to visualize decision tree

Tags: python, scikit-learn, visualization, dtreeviz

I love the decision tree visualisations available from [Dtreeviz library - GitHub](https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz) , and can duplicate this using

```py
# Install libraries
!pip install dtreeviz
!apt-get install graphviz

# Sample code
from sklearn.datasets import *
from sklearn import tree
from dtreeviz.trees import *
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

classifier = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=4)
cancer = load_breast_cancer()

classifier.fit(cancer.data, cancer.target)
viz = dtreeviz(classifier,
               cancer.data,
               cancer.target,
               target_name='cancer',
               feature_names=cancer.feature_names, 
               class_names=["malignant", "benign"],
               fancy=False) 

display(HTML(viz.svg()))
```

However, when I apply the above to a dtree I made myself, the code bombs out because my data is in a pandas DF (or a np array), not a scikit-learn bunch object.

Now, over at [Sci-kit learn - How to create a Bunch object](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-create-a-bunch-object) they tell me pretty sternly not to try to create a bunch object; but I also do not have the skills to convert my DF or NP array to something that the viz function, above, will accept.

We can suppose my DF has nine features and a target, called 'Feature01', 'Feature02', etc and 'Target01'.

This I would normally split thusly

```py
FeatDF  = FullDF.drop( columns = ["Target01"])
LabelDF = FullDF["Target01"]
```

and then set on my merry way to assign a classifier, or if for ML, create a test/train split.

None of this is helpful when calling `dtreeviz` - which is expecting things like  "feature_names" (which I take is something included in the "bunch" object). And since I can't convert my DF to a bunch, I'm very much stuck. Oh bring your wisdom, please.

**Update**: I guess any simple DF would illustrate my conundrum. We could just swing with

```
import pandas as pd

Things = {'Feature01': [3,4,5,0], 
          'Feature02': [4,5,6,0], 
          'Feature03': [1,2,3,8], 
          'Target01': ['Red','Blue','Teal','Red']}
DF = pd.DataFrame(Things,
                  columns= ['Feature01', 'Feature02', 
                            'Feature02', 'Target01'])
```

as an example DF. Now, would I then go

```
DataNP = DF.to_numpy()
classifier.fit(DF.data, DF.target)
feature_names = ['Feature01', 'Feature02', 'Feature03'] 
#..and what if I have 50 features...

viz = dtreeviz(classifier,
               DF.data,
               DF.target,
               target_name='Target01',
               feature_names=feature_names, 
               class_names=["Red", "Blue", "Teal"],
               fancy=False)
```

or is this daft? Thanks for the guidance so far!

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] so we can replicate the issue?

Comment: Could you also provide the way you try to call the dtreeviz? Because I know how you can construct a dataframe, but I want to know how you call the function with the dataframe and what the error is you get.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- sklearn's decision tree needs numerical target values
- You can use sklearn's `LabelEncoder` to transform your strings to integers

  ```
  from sklearn import preprocessing

  label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
  label_encoder.fit(df.Target01)

  df['target'] = label_encoder.transform(df.Target01)
  ```
- `dtreeviz` expects the `class_names` to be a `list` or `dict`, so let's get it from our `label_encoder`

  ```
  class_names = list(label_encoder.classes_)
  ```

**Complete code**

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing, tree
from dtreeviz.trees import dtreeviz

Things = {'Feature01': [3,4,5,0], 
          'Feature02': [4,5,6,0], 
          'Feature03': [1,2,3,8], 
          'Target01': ['Red','Blue','Teal','Red']}
df = pd.DataFrame(Things,
                  columns= ['Feature01', 'Feature02', 
                            'Feature02', 'Target01']) 

label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
label_encoder.fit(df.Target01)
df['target'] = label_encoder.transform(df.Target01)

classifier = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
classifier.fit(df.iloc[:,:3], df.target)

dtreeviz(classifier,
         df.iloc[:,:3],
         df.target,
         target_name='toy',
         feature_names=df.columns[0:3],
         class_names=list(label_encoder.classes_)
         )
```

[image]

---

**Old answer**

Let's use the cancer dataset to create a Pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(cancer.data, columns=cancer.feature_names)
df['target'] = cancer.target
```

which gives us the following dataframe.

```
mean radius mean texture    mean perimeter  mean area   mean smoothness mean compactness    mean concavity  mean concave points mean symmetry   mean fractal dimension  radius error    texture error   perimeter error area error  smoothness error    compactness error   concavity error concave points error    symmetry error  fractal dimension error worst radius    worst texture   worst perimeter worst area  worst smoothness    worst compactness   worst concavity worst concave points    worst symmetry  worst fractal dimension target
0   17.99   10.38   122.8   1001.0  0.1184  0.2776  0.3001  0.1471  0.2419  0.07871 1.095   0.9053  8.589   153.4   0.006399    0.04904 0.05373 0.01587 0.03003 0.006193    25.38   17.33   184.6   2019.0  0.1622  0.6656  0.7119  0.2654  0.4601  0.1189  0
1   20.57   17.77   132.9   1326.0  0.08474 0.07864 0.0869  0.07017 0.1812  0.05667 0.5435  0.7339  3.398   74.08   0.005225    0.01308 0.0186  0.0134  0.01389 0.003532    24.99   23.41   158.8   1956.0  0.1238  0.1866  0.2416  0.186   0.275   0.08902 0
2   19.69   21.25   130.0   1203.0  0.1096  0.1599  0.1974  0.1279  0.2069  0.05999 0.7456  0.7869  4.585   94.03   0.00615 0.04006 0.03832 0.02058 0.0225  0.004571    23.57   25.53   152.5   1709.0  0.1444  0.4245  0.4504  0.243   0.3613  0.08758 0
[...]
568 7.76    24.54   47.92   181.0   0.05263 0.04362 0.0 0.0 0.1587  0.05884 0.3857  1.428   2.548   19.15   0.007189    0.00466 0.0 0.0 0.02676 0.002783    9.456   30.37   59.16   268.6   0.08996 0.06444 0.0 0.0 0.2871  0.07039 1
```

and for your classifier it can be used in the following way.

```
classifier.fit(df.iloc[:,:-1], df.target)
```

i.e. just take all but the last column as training/input and the `target` column as the output/target.

The same for the visualization:

```
viz = dtreeviz(classifier,
               df.iloc[:,:-1],
               df.target,
               target_name='cancer',
               feature_names=df.columns[0:-1],
               class_names=["malignant", "benign"])
```

Comment: Thank you for stepping in once more. In the cancer set, the targets are integers, right? However,  when I use the toy df, and `class_names = ["Red", "Blue", "Teal"]`   I get  `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' ` , and when  I say  `class_names = list(DF['Target01'].unique()) ` it raises an ominous `KeyError: 3 ` . Does any of this make sense?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that in the second part, above, I had also changed Red to 1, Blue to 2, and Teal to 3...

Comment: @RandomForestRanger: check the updated answer, hope that works for you!

Comment: Gosh. Elegant. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused with the example provided in the documentation.

[Here](https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz#classification-decision-tree) let's have a look at the example with the iris dataset.

```py
from sklearn.datasets import *

# Loading iris data
iris = load_iris()

# Type of iris
type(iris)
<class 'sklearn.utils.Bunch'>
```

The dataset is stored as an sklearn Bunch object as you have mentioned.

But the `dtreeviz` does not use this object in any of its parameters. All the parameters are numpy arrays.

```py
# Iris data - parameter
type(iris.data)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

# Shape
data.data.shape
(150, 4)
```

So it is clear that the `dtreeviz` method is working with numpy arrays and there is not use of the Bunch object. In your case, the feature names is nothing by the column names of the selected features.

**Update**

```py
# Replace the following the the sample code to fit your dataframe
cancer.data <> DF.iloc[:, :-1]
cancer.target <> DF['Target01']

# Other parameters
feature_names = DF.columns[:-1]
class_names = DF['Target01'].unique()
```

Comment: thank you. You are absolutely right about my being confused! Let's say I take the above DF - do I convert to a single numpy array and roll with it? Doesn't seem to work. Moreover, in the example way up top, cancer.data and cancer.target are not colls - so there seems to be something else going on (apart from feature_names = colls (which I get)). At the most basic level: how would you deal with the toy DF to make it dtreeviz-friendly? Again, many thanks.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the way you can integrate your sample dataframe `DF`. It includes if you have a large number of features and labels as well. If you find it helpful, select the checkbox next to answer. Cheers!

Comment: thanks. I think we are close... Perhaps I'm just making an obvious mistake. Above returns error saying `Exception: class_names must be dict or sequence, not ndarray.` If I then replace `class_names = DF['Target01'].unique()` with `class_names = ["Red", "Blue", "Teal"]`, I'm served with       `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`.

Comment: It expects a `list` of the class names. Your error message specifies that you're multiplying the list with some value. Make sure you only assign a single list of elements to the `class_names` Try **list(DF['Target01'].unique())**

Comment: If you find the solution helpful, give it an upvote and select the checkbox to accept the solution.

Comment: still no cigar. `class_names = list(DF['Target01'].unique()  ` returns the same `TypeError`. Cannot for the life of me make it work.